# Accommodation checking assignment

Tags: javascript, html

We have an assignment to make a basic tour cost calculator using a combination of javascript and html. I was fixing errors using the developer console when suddenly the errors all vanished, along with all content on the page. Nothing loads anymore.
I've tried removing certain parts of the code one at a time to try and find what is causing this, but i can't find anything. Can anyone spot the problem(s) thats causing this? Thanks!

```
<script>
var dailycost = 0;
var radiobutton;
var checkbox;
var duration = 0;
var total = 0;

function getcost(){
        for (var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
            radiobutton = document.getElementByID("accomodation" + i);
            if (radiobutton.checked == true){
                dailycost = radiobutton.value;
            }
        }
        if (dailycost == 0){
            alert("No accomodation type was selected.");
            return;
        }

    checkbox = document.getElementByID("peakSeason");
        if (checkbox.checked == true){
            dailyCost = parseFloat(dailycost) + 20;
        }
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
            radiobutton = document.getElementByID("duration");
            if (radiobutton.checked == true){
            duration = radioButton.value;
            }
        }
        if (duration == 0){
            alert("A duration was not selected.");
            return;
    }
        totalcost = dailycost * duration;
        totalcost = math.round(totalcost);
        alert("This tour will cost " + totalcost +'$');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If theres no issue there (unlikely, but possible, i suppose), the problem might be in the following HTML here: https://pastebin.com/dRqsWykf

Comment: declare totalcost as var

Comment: `Can anyone spot the problem(s) thats causing this?` - no, I've had browsers do that too, I mean your code still has about 30 errors, but that's not why the console stopped working - just try restarting the browser - try debugging a different page, if that also doesn't work, then you've done something to your browser - re-install the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was so many various typos/mistakes. Fixes are below:

- radiobutton != radioButton
- missing ID's for accomodation
- missing `+ i` after duration
- math.round != Math.round

```js
    var dailycost = 0;
    var radiobutton;
    var checkbox;
    var duration = 0;
    var total = 0;

 function getcost(){
      for (var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
             radiobutton = document.getElementById("accomodation" + i);
       if (radiobutton.checked == true){
        dailycost = radiobutton.value;
       }
      }
      if (dailycost == 0){
       alert("No accomodation type was selected.");
       return;
      }
    
      checkbox = document.getElementById("peakseason");
      if (checkbox.checked == true){
       dailycost = parseFloat(dailycost) + 20;
      }
      for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
       radiobutton = document.getElementById("duration" + i);
       if (radiobutton.checked == true){
    duration = radiobutton.value;
       }
      }
      if (duration == 0){
       alert("A duration was not selected.");
       return;
  }
      totalcost = dailycost * duration;
      totalcost = Math.round(totalcost);
      alert("This tour will cost " + totalcost +'$');
     }
```

```html
<h1>USA Tour Cost Calculator</h1>
<h4>Complete the following form to calculate the cost of your tour.</h4>
<form name="tourform">
<p>Accomodation Type:<br>
<input type="radio" name="accomodation" id="accomodation1" value="95.5"> Camping<br>
<input type="radio" name="accomodation" id="accomodation2" value="140.3"> Budget Hotel<br>
<input type="radio" name="accomodation" id="accomodation3" value="170.7"> Premier Hotel<br>
 
<p><label for="peakseason">Click here if you are traveling between June and August.</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="peakseason" name="peakseason"></p>
 
<p>Tour Duration:<br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" id="duration1" value="4"> <label for="duration1">4 days</label><br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" id="duration2" value="7"> <label for="duration1">7 days</label><br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" id="duration3" value="14"> <label for="duration1">14 days</label><br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" id="duration4" value="20"> <label for="duration1">20 days</label><br><br>
 
<input type ="button" value ="Calculate" onClick="getcost();">
<input type ="reset" value ="Reset"></p>
</form>
```

I'd simplify it though, to the below (Drop the loops, avoid having to ID every input, and avoid adding variables outside the function):

```js
function getcost(){
  const acc = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=accomodation]:checked');
  
  if (!acc.length) {
    alert("No accomodation type was selected.");
    return;
  }
  
  let dailycost = parseFloat(acc[0].value);

  const checkbox = document.getElementById("peakseason");
  if (checkbox.checked){
    dailycost += 20;
  }
  
  const durationInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=duration]:checked');
  
  if (!durationInput.length) {
    alert("A duration was not selected.");
    return;
  }
  
  const duration = durationInput[0].value;
  
  const totalcost = Math.round(dailycost * duration);
  alert("This tour will cost " + totalcost +'$');
}
```

```html
<h1>USA Tour Cost Calculator</h1>
<h4>Complete the following form to calculate the cost of your tour.</h4>
<form name="tourform">
<p>Accomodation Type:<br>
<input type="radio" name="accomodation" value="95.5"> Camping<br>
<input type="radio" name="accomodation" value="140.3"> Budget Hotel<br>
<input type="radio" name="accomodation" value="170.7"> Premier Hotel<br>
 
<p><label for="peakseason">Click here if you are traveling between June and August.</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="peakseason" name="peakseason"></p>
 
<p>Tour Duration:<br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" value="4"> <label for="duration1">4 days</label><br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" value="7"> <label for="duration1">7 days</label><br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" value="14"> <label for="duration1">14 days</label><br>
<input type ="radio" name="duration" value="20"> <label for="duration1">20 days</label><br><br>
 
<input type ="button" value="Calculate" onClick="getcost();">
<input type ="reset" value="Reset"></p>
</form>
```